# Mongoose return aggregate result like mongoose paginate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have the following code in Node.js:

```
exports.getProfiles = async function(query, page, limit, val){
    var options = {
        page,
        limit
    };

    let clause =  [                                               
        {$project:{name:{$concat:["$firstName"," ","$lastName"]}, docs: '$$ROOT' }},
        {$match:{name:new RegExp(val, 'i')}}                       
    ];

    function getProfileByFullName (callback) {
        Profile.aggregate(clause, function (err, result) {
            if (err) 
                return callback(err);
            if (result.length)
                return callback(null, result[0]);
        })
    };

    try {
        var profiles = await Profile.paginate(query, options);
        console.log('after pagination: ');
        console.log(profiles);
        getProfileByFullName(function (err, res) {
            profiles = res;
            console.log('function call: ');
            console.log(profiles);
        });
        console.log('after the function call: ');
        console.log(profiles);
        return profiles;
    } catch (e) {
        throw Error('Error while Paginating Profiles: ' + e);
    }
}
```

What this should do is return a list of mongo documents based on either the users(Profiles) partial or full name. The mongo document has the name split and stored by firstName and lastName values:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName:      {type: String, default: ''},
    lastName:       {type: String, default: ''},
    dateOfBirth:    {type: Date, default: null},
    address:        {type: String, default: ''},
    maritalStatus:  {type: String, default: ''},
    contactPhone:   {type: String, default: ''},
    contactEmail:   {type: String, default: ''},
    gender:         {type: String, default: ''},
    occupation:     {type: String, default: ''}
});

UserProfileSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)
const UserProfile = mongoose.model('UserProfile', UserProfileSchema)

module.exports = UserProfile;
```

My problem is that when I try to return the result from the aggregate function it won't return a thing.

The result is not empty, when I print it via console.log it will print the correct document. I'm calling this function from a controller what gets called from express routes.

Can you guys help me?

### EDIT:

The output is:

```
after pagination: 
{ docs: [], total: 0, limit: 100, page: 1, pages: 1 }
after the function call: 
{ docs: [], total: 0, limit: 100, page: 1, pages: 1 }
GET /api/profiles/search/?firstName=Tischler%20Krist%C3%B3f&lastName=Tischler%20Krist%C3%B3f 200 396.098 ms - 114
function call: 
{ _id: 5a9cf0298e28e3773f19def1,
  name: 'Tischler Kristóf',
  docs: 
   { _id: 5a9cf0298e28e3773f19def1,
     occupation: 'Software Developer',
     gender: 'Male',
     contactEmail: 'asd@asd.com',
     contactPhone: '+363083741246214',
     maritalStatus: 'Single',
     address: '64343 Valahol, Király utca 56.',
     dateOfBirth: 1995-08-25T22:00:00.000Z,
     lastName: 'Kristóf',
     firstName: 'Tischler',
     __v: 0 } }
```

### EDIT:

I've updated the code, because I was missing the callback parameter in the getProfileByFullName function. As you can see, I'm clearly messing something up, because the console logs are out of order, I think I'm missing a crucial thing here...

Comment: Can you please add the logging??

Comment: Yes, I'll attach them tonight after I get home.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as it seems I was overcomplicating things and a simple:

```
var profiles = await Profile.aggregate(clause);
return profiles;
```

And modifying, then returning the values elsewhere solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to perform some operations in the documents returned but in other place in your script.

If so, you need to declare a array, and push every document that is returned into the array, like this:

```
var resultArray = [];               // Declare an array

function getProfileByFullName () {
    Profile.aggregate(clause, function (err, result) {
          console.log('Inside the aggregate function: ');
          console.log(result);
        // How do I return the result from here, like the pagination below and store it in a variable???
        resultArray.push(result);   // Push into the array
    })
};

console.log(resultArray);           // Do stuff with the documents in the array
```

Comment: This solution didn't fix my problem, maybe I wasn't clear on it. I've updated  the question for you to better understand it.